# probability, hazard rate

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $F(x)$ has an increasing hazard rate, i.e. $\frac{f(x)}{1 - F(x)}$ is increasing in $x$. Is it true that $\frac{f(x+a)}{1 - F(x)}$ is increasing in $x$ for any $a \geq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

*No*, here is a counter-example:

The $[0,1]$ triangle distribution has an increasing hazard rate which is:

$\frac{2x}{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}$ for $x\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{1-x}$ for $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ (both increasing).

But, let $a=\frac{1}{2}$:

$\frac{f(x+a)}{1-F(x)}=\frac{4-x}{2x^2}$ which is decreasing for $x\in{\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]}$